# How to have the python type and the constraints of a sqlalchemy column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

By doing this :

```
    columns = [[column.name, column.type] for column in inspect(table).c]
    print(columns)
```

I managed to get the name and the type of a column.
But the type I get is on the sqlalchemy format, not in python format.
I would also like to know if the table is nullable.

For example, if we have this column :

```
    username = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
```

I would like to get something like :

```
    ["username", str, 45, False]
```

Comment: You need to type map it. you have to write custom code for that.

Comment: @farhanpirzadaa Ok but how though ? I dont understand how to do it. Most of the tutorials of mapping talks about declarative table and default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Python type from the column's type's `python_type` attribute, `length` from the `type`, `nullable` from the column:

```
>>> username = sa.Column(sa.String(45), nullable=False)
>>> username.type.python_type
<class 'str'>
>>> username.type.length
45
>>> username.nullable
False
```